# Not Able to Run Pyspark in Google Colab

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

hi I am trying to run pyspark on google colab using following code :

```
!apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null
!wget -q http://apache.osuosl.org/spark/spark-2.4.5/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
!tar xf spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
!pip install -q findspark
```

```
import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/content/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7"
```

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
```

I am getting following error :

```
/content/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py in _launch_gateway(conf, insecure)
    106 
    107             if not os.path.isfile(conn_info_file):
--> 108                 raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
    109 
    110             with open(conn_info_file, "rb") as info:

Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

**NOTE  : I was able to run this code till afternoon today, suddenly this error started coming in the evening**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google collab has java pre installed. So if you just run

```
!pip install pyspark
```

And then use spark it works.. no need of findspark or other unnecessary library.

Comment: Could you please say more about starting a session, until reading the file ?

Answer (score 2):

Please check if wget is working. If not, upload the latest version of apache-spark to google drive and unpack it to the google collaboratory and then add the path as given. Your code is not working because it is not able to find the spark folder. wget is not working

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps that I start with always:
1st to remove unnecessary ubuntu errors or Java port errors

```
!sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:vikoadi/ppa
!sudo apt update
```

second code for fresh start

```
!pip install pyspark
```

third code fresh java and latest spark table from the website (you can change the link if it shows error and pickup any you like)

```
!apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null
!wget -q https://www-us.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-3.1.1/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz
!tar xf spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz
!pip install -q findspark
```

4th code creating a session or configure the size or memory you need here 4G for example

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
spark=SparkSession.builder.appName('sol').getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("spark.driver.memory","4g")
```

5th code to check the session on any my data

```
from google.colab import files
files.upload() #to upload the testing file for example mydata.csv 
dataset = spark.read.csv('mydata.csv',inferSchema=True, header =True)
dataset.printSchema()
```

Then i hope it's all good. Leave a comment if it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Just the following commands

Cell1

```
!pip install pyspark
```

Cell 2

```
spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .master("local")\
    .appName("Colab")\
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.option("header",True).format("csv").load(url)
df.show()
```